# PyOpenGL .obj file not displayed correctly

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

Why is my object file not displaying correctly... This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is the code i have:

```
    #self.verts   -   vertices 
    #self.norms   -   normals 
    #self.faces   -   faces

    for i in range(len(self.verts)):
        GL.glNormal3d(self.norms[i][0], self.norms[i][1], self.norms[i][2])
        GL.glVertex3f(self.verts[i][0], self.verts[i][1], self.verts[i][2])
```

The working code:

```
            GL.glNormal3f(self.norms[n1 - 1][0], self.norms[n1 - 1][1], self.norms[n1 - 1][2])
            GL.glVertex3f(self.verts[v1 - 1][0], self.verts[v1 - 1][1], self.verts[v1 - 1][2])


            GL.glNormal3f(self.norms[n2 - 1][0], self.norms[n2 - 1][1], self.norms[n2 - 1][2])
            GL.glVertex3f(self.verts[v2 - 1][0], self.verts[v2 - 1][1], self.verts[v2 - 1][2])


            GL.glNormal3f(self.norms[n3 - 1][0], self.norms[n3 - 1][1], self.norms[n3 - 1][2])
            GL.glVertex3f(self.verts[v3 - 1][0], self.verts[v3 - 1][1], self.verts[v3 - 1][2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.obj doesn't work that way;](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)

you need to follow what is put in the lines starting with `f` aka the [face definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Face_definitions).

Comment: I was not sure what was the purpose of faces... Fixed it and added the working code...